# if-else statement with 2 level checking

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

1) I have 5 data which save in note pad, only data4 have the word 'Form', however it appear 4 times in my results which show that it occur (e.g.: C9=[1 1 1 1]). How would I modify it to only C9=[1]. Then the overall results include data1 until data5 would be C9=[0 0 0 1 0]

```
data1=<form name="yahoo" method="post" action="yahoo.php">
data2=n/a
data3=<form>
data4=<form name="yahoo" method="post" action="yahoo.php" onsubmit="return ValidateFormYahoo()">
```

data5=onsubmit="return ValidateFormYahoo()"

Now my code:

```
 A9 = {'Form'};%check domain
 D9 = {'Validate'};%check domain

data1=  importdata('f9_data1');
data2 = importdata('f9_data2');
data3 = importdata('f9_data3');
data4 = importdata('f9_data4');
data5 = importdata('f9_data5');


C9_data1=any(cellfun(@(n) ~isempty(n), strfind(data1, A9{1}& D9{1})))
C9_data2=any(cellfun(@(n) ~isempty(n), strfind(data2, A9{1}& D9{1})))
C9_data3=any(cellfun(@(n) ~isempty(n), strfind(data3, A9{1}& D9{1})))
C9_data4=any(cellfun(@(n) ~isempty(n), strfind(data4, A9{1}& D9{1})))
C9_data5=any(cellfun(@(n) ~isempty(n), strfind(data5, A9{1}& D9{1})))
```

E9=[C9_data1;C9_data2;C9_data3;C9_data4;C9_data5]

I want to check is that 'form' & 'validate' occur at the same time, then return 0, also if nth then return 0, else if only 'form' or 'validate' then return 1
[data1 data2 data3 data4 data5]=[1 0 1 0 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to aggregate into one value, you can say this:

```
C9=any((cellfun(@(n) ~isempty(n), strfind(data4, A9{1}))));
```

The `any` function returns true if any of the values in the input array is not zero.

For the second question, if you used `any`, the result is boolean value (true or false), then you can just do a logical AND.

```
C9=any((cellfun(@(n) ~isempty(n), strfind(data4, A9{1})))) && any((cellfun(@(n) ~isempty(n), strfind(data4, D9{1}))));
```

However, I'm not sure what your data file is and what you are trying to say. The `importdata` function most often returns a structure with multiple fields, and the `strfind` function operates on either a string or a cell array of strings, but not structures. So the reason you get a vector as output puzzles me. It might help if you describe your input data.

Comment: +1. Replace `cellfun(@(n) ~isempty(n), ...)` with `~cellfun('isempty', ...)` and enjoy ~100× speed increase :)

Comment: @shaoy185, I have edited as above. How to check is that 'form' & 'validate' occur at the same time, then return 0, also if ntg (dont have 'validate' & 'form' at the same time) then return 0, else if only 'form' or 'validate' then return 1? e.g. [data1 data2 data3 data4 data5]=[1 0 1 0 1]

Comment: The "&" operator in MATLAB means bitwise AND, so it does not work here on two strings. The "&&" operator is logical AND, which connects two boolean values (true or false) and returns true if both of the boolean values are true. Thus the code for that is like the one in my answer. `any(...) && any(...)`